# Is it standard practice to note late arrival of a board member in minutes?

Tags: business-writing

In the board meeting of a company, is it customary to note in minutes if a board member arrived late? Is there any difference between someone coming a minute late, and another coming five minutes late? How about someone leaving early? What are standard practices?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about business practice, not writing.

Comment: Maybe a better fit for the Workplace SE site? https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: any mod can feel free to move it there if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Not in our board meetings. All that goes in the minutes are things relevant to the business; primarily issues or questions considered and decisions made (or narrowed, or not made), and the particular vote.

When people arrived is irrelevant; if somebody is not there for a vote, mark them "not present". The same for discussions tabled without a vote.

I don't care if somebody arrives in bathing suit wearing a snorkel, it is not relevant to their ability to do business.

If they arrive late, leave early, disappear in the middle for half an hour, whatever.